# Expected identifier but got 'ILLEGAL' - Solidity

Tags: parsing, error-handling, compiler-errors, solidity

[>>>for Code tap here<<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYOm7.png)

***ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'ILLEGAL'
--> contracts/nftgirl.sol:56:9:
|
56 | bool public started;
| ^***

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Have you closed all the previous functions, loops and contracts using `}` before inheritance? like @ewong mentioned please include your code as text in your Question

Answer (score 0):

from my experience the ILLEGAL means your trying to compile something that's not allowed or doesn't make sense, so to speak.

it could be a simple typo of accidentally using a character such a `/` improperly.

Please paste your code for a more accurate answer.